# ReactiveMongo reference annotations

Tags: mongodb, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

I have some general questions about ReactiveMongo plugin. I have previously used Morphia with Play and we have now migrated to scala and I would like to clarify some things.

1) Is it a good practise to use @References annotations similar to Morphia? e.g. https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/wiki/ReferenceAnnotation
For example Morphia saves the following object in the DB and they have lazy_load which retrieves the object if required:

```
...[additional fields],
"accManager": {
    "$ref": "User",
    "$id": ObjectId("5603a77e0b6d3849aace3727")
}
...[additional fields]
```

2) How can I achieve that in ReactiveMongo? Is it possible to do this automatically or should I manually create another field as let's say : referenceName: BSONObjectID or referenceName: String?